# Underscores menu not toggle not working on 2nd menu

Tags: wordpress, responsive, underscores-wp

I added a second nav menu in underscores in the content area after the header but when I click to toggle it doesn't seem to be working. Code below:

Registering Nav Menu

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'themeName' ),
        'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Secondary', 'themeName' ),
    ) );
```

Menu 1 - header.php

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( '☰ Main Menu', 'themeName' ); ?></button>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Menu 2 - page-template.php

```
<nav  id="secondary-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="secondary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( '☰ Utility Menu', 'themeName' ); ?></button>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-2', 'menu_id' => 'secondary-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

One thing I did notice is that the Primary Menu which is working on toggle has an additional ***nav-menu*** class added by navigation.js

The Secondary Menu does not have this class and I believe this is the root cause of my issue but I just can't figure it out. I want to understand why this is happening and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It was late, I was tired, typo in my JS call, had romt instead of rotm. Saw it instantly with fresh eyes! Ain't that always how it goes.